# How can I pass data via editActionsForRowAt to a Viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to pass data from my tableview to another viewcontroller. 
I do not know how to do this, but I've tried this and it's not working:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

        let eventDB = self.events[indexPath.row]
        self.events.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableViewHome.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.removeFromDB(event: eventDB)
        print(self.tableViewHome)
    }

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in

        let EC = EditEventController()
        EC.dateTextfield.text = self.events[indexPath.row].dateTitle
        EC.titleTextfield.text = self.events[indexPath.row].eventTitle
        EC.repeatTextfield.text = self.events[indexPath.row].repeatTime

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(EC, animated: true)

        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToEditEvent", sender: self)

    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    return [delete, edit]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the IBOutlets in your `EditEventController` are nil until you actually do the `pushViewController`, which is why you're seeing them not getting set.

What I would recommend doing is add an `event` (or `originalEvent`) property to your `EditEventController`, and then in your `EditEventController`'s `viewWillAppear` function, then set the text properties of the outlets.

That is, in your `EditEventController`:

```
var originalEvent : Event? // or whatever you've named this structure/object

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard let originalEvent = originalEvent else {
        return
    }

    self.dateTextfield.text = originalEvent.dateTitle
    self.titleTextfield.text = originalEvent.eventTitle
    self.repeatTextfield.text = originalEvent.repeatTime
}
```

Then, in your `UITableViewRowAction`:

```
let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in

    let eec = EditEventController()
    eec.originalEvent = self.events[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(eec, animated: true)
}
```

Also, notice I made the `EditEventController` instance all lowercase?  [Starting with a lowercase letter is the standard way to start naming a variable in Swift](https://andybargh.com/variables-and-constants-in-swift/).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! 
But I'm not getting it working properly. I can not declare "originalEvent" without making it optional. When I run the code, it crashes and I get the error message "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: so, declare `originalEvent` an optional and then just unwrap it (I've modified my answer to show how)